How to make a backgroud-image good fit?
How can I make a background image a good fit? My image size is 1920x750
Expectation

This is what I get

It cuts off my image
and I try with background-image: contain; and I get:



.banner1 {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/300');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 750px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  justify-content: end;
  padding: 8% 5%;
  align-items: end;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  h5 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  span {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 23px;
  }
}
<section class="banner1">
  <h5>Test1</h5>
  <span>Test1 subtitle</span>
  <div>Discover More</div>
</section>
<section class="banner2">
  <h5>Test1</h5>
  <span>Test2 subtitle.</span>
  <div>Discover More</div>
</section>
<section class="banner3">
  <h5>Test3</h5>
  <span>Test3 subtitle</span>
  <div>Discover More</div>
</section>




Hi. This question is similar to this one: Fit background image to div. I'd suggest you have a look as there's some good answers that'll help you. Good luck.

You have padding on the section, to get that included in the width and height you have set, rather than adding extra, set box-sizing: border box. And if you always want the whole image to show, regardless of viewport aspect-ratio, then set it to contain rather than cover (but you'll want to think about the min-height a bit more, what does it mean on small viewports for example?).

The CSS property you're looking for is called background-size. From the images you've attached, it looks like you need to add background-size: contain; to your .banner1 class. For more info on this property see the MDN docs here
